# sql server create fictional 0 values for average determination

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry for the terrible title. I can only describe the situation.

I have a database table named User with columns Username and ID, and a table name UserScore with a integer column called Score in it.

I want to create an average of the Score, so basically i use `avg(Score) as AverageScore` to get my average.

The problem is that not every user in my database has a UserScore record but i do want to count them in, and make their score 0 without having to make records for them.

how do i do this without having to extract the data to my program and making an average there?

Answer (score 2):

Select from your `User` table and use a *left join* on the `UserScore` table. Then use `coalesce` (or `isnull`, your choice here) to take the NULLs into account as zero:

```
select avg(coalesce(Score,0)) as AverageScore
from User
left outer join UserScore on User.ID = UserScore.UserID
```

Or, if you wanted to get *each* user's average score, you can follow a similar principle:

```
select User.Username, coalesce(avg(Score),0) as AverageScore
from User
left outer join UserScore on User.ID = UserScore.UserID
group by User.Username
```

*Note, I'm assuming your `UserScore` table has a column `UserID`.*

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.Username,AVG(ISNULL(us.Score,0))
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN UserScore us on u.Id=us.UserId
GROUP BY u.Username
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the coalesce function to replace missing scores with zero.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

```
select avg(coalesce(Score, 0)) as AverageScore
from User
left join UserScore on User.ID = UserScore.ID
group by User.ID
```